# When my app runs on Android Studio Simulator, Text alignment centered as expected, But when it runs on Samsung S2 text alignment become right

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Android Studio:

When my app runs on Simulator

text alignment center as expected

but when it runs on Samsung S2

text align becomes right.

Samsung S2 Android version 4.1.2

Simulator Android 6

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/VersesEnglish"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Text HERE"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#813b1a"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />
```

Comment: did you try android:gravity = 'center'

Comment: yes, I tried  android:layout_gravity="center"  but the same issue

Comment: i tried android:gravity = 'center' it works.. thanks so much

Comment: please post it in an answer to check it resolved

Comment: Ok i tried it works but I need the gravity to be top also + center, what can i do for that

Comment: similar to layout_gravity, you can use android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" or android:gravity="top|center"

Comment: wow so perfect, great advice bro. thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try android:gravity = 'center', as 'android:gravity' sets the gravity of the contents.